# Input Method with other language on CefSharp.WPF

Tags: wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I implemented an application with CefSharp.WPF, 51.0.0.

It browses my web app well, however, I have a huge problem.

That is "IME". I use Korean but it won't shows my language in `input` or `textarea`.

[image]

I couldn't find to solve this problem though it issued several years ago.

Is there somebody fix it? It makes me frustrated.

Comment: There is already an open issue on `GitHub`, please search there before posting in future. Thanks. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1262

Comment: @amaitland I saw that post already,  but i didn't understand clearly maybe im not good at english,  if you don't mind would you give me some hints for me if it was fixed

Comment: oh you've already commented,  sorry

Comment: @amaitland Can I know that version was fixed. I think I should downgrade it.

Comment: So long ago, I don't remember. You'll have to look on the `CEF` issue tracker.

Comment: @amaitland I tried using CefSharp.WinForm, it is working IME well. I think it's not a CEF issue.

Comment: It's an issue with `CEF` when using `offscreen rendering`.